# How to add a user to a rails app manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, postgresql, legacy

I've been assigned to work on a legacy Rails app, and nobody has a development environment working. I've gotten everything up and running, but I can't create a new user on my development environment because the facebook api doesn't like the api call originating from an IP that isn't the production server, and the mailer for the non facebook signup times out for the same reason. I've narrowed it down to a couple options:

- Figure out a way to get the facebook api to accept the request from my development box
- Fix the mailer or wrap it in a conditional so that email confirmation is not required in the development environment
- Manually add a user to the database

Which option is best, and how would I go about doing it? I'm relatively new to rails and backend programming. Options one and two seem like potential security risks, but I have no idea how to go about doing option 3. I tried adding User.create([{email: '(redacted)'}, {password: '(redacted)'}]) to the seeds.rb file and running db:seed with no luck.

Suggestions?

Comment: Create a test app at developers.facebook.com for the production app

Answer (score 4):

Your easiest option is definitely simply to create the new user manually. Instead of launching your rails server (`$ rails s`), launch your rails *console* (`$ rails c`). From this command line (which is identical to the debugger, if you've ever used that before), you may create a user and save it. You will still be subject to the validations in the User model, but something *along the lines* of the following should work:

```
new_user = User.new( email: 'myemail@example.com', name: 'Joe Smith' )
new_user.save
```

As long as you match the validations of the model, and connect to the appropriate database, this is a very simple approach. To connect to the right database, either update config/database.yml so that your development environment is the one you want to hit, or run specifically in the correct environment (if it's production, as you implied, simply run `$ rails c RAILS_ENV=production` instead of the aforementioned`$ rails c`).